# having a 'backup' css file?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Is there any way to call a stylesheet, and *only* if it is not available, call a stylesheet from another location?

Something like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.somewhere.com/css/style.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local/style.css" />
```

But **only** call the second one if the first is not available?  I don't want to make 2 calls if it is unnecessary.  Thank you.

EDIT: This is because I noticed at work, my CDN is blocked, so no styles show up but the site does.  I am assuming a lot of places may have the same block (firewall blocking web applications).  So then I would like to grab the css from the local copy.

Comment: Regardless of the second stylesheet being in a different location, isn't the browser clever enough to figure out they're the same and not bother loading it?  I thought this is what browsers did?

Comment: Because the reason I mentioned below, I think this question is wrong in terms of programming habits. It assumes that the content delivery network can break down. It can, but it simply isn't worth the effort to have a workaround. Might be needed 1 times out of 10 million.

Comment: @Kezzer: no, the browsers don't know if two stylesheets are identical. They do not even check if they were. However, rule rewrites apply.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I cannot think of any reason to have two CSS files, using one as a fallback..

Comment: I noticed at work, my CDN is blocked, so no styles show up.  I am assuming a lot of places may have the same block (firewall blocking web applications), but no the site itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible in pure HTML markup.  However, you could do this **server-side** with a simple script, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
if first style does not exist:
    output <link> to second sheet
else
    output <link> to primary sheet
```

In reality, though, your style sheets are likely to be cached by the browser, so it's hardly putting a burden on the end-user.  You could simply order the s so that the 'second' style sheet loads first, and the primary sheet loads second.  This would cause the primary sheet to override anything in the secondary sheet... but if the primary sheet wasn't available, the secondary sheet would still work as intended.

Comment: I'm not even sure that's possible - how would the JS determine if the first stylesheet existed?

Comment: I said server-side.  Not JavaScript.

Comment: My mistake. One would think that if he can do a server-side check, he can hopefully just upload it to the CDN, though. :)

Comment: Well that depends on whether he has access to the remote server, and whether he means the second sheet is local as in client-side, or local as in local to his server!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript/AJAX is strongly **not recommended** due to its very unpredictable behavior (I'm not talking about cross-browser compatibility, but some users turned it off.)

If I were you, I'd check the existence of the first given CSS **server side** and insert the href accordingly.

Also keep in mind, that if you really have to use this kind of mechanism to make sure, then you're saying your servers are not reliable.

Comment: Not saying that it is not reliable, but I noticed at work, it is blocked, so no styles show up.  I am assuming a lot of places may have the same block (firewall blocking web applications), but no thte site itself.

Comment: The problem is that my server can always reach my cdn, it is the user I am worried about... but I guess this might just be something I have to deal with.

Comment: Then I recommend you to have a look at ways you can prepare your website to be accessible. With well used accessibility rules, your site can be used without stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

No, because LINK elements itself are static ("dumb"). So you either need JavaScript, GreaseMonkey (on Firefox but that's JavaScript, too) or you really have to ask for both.

The order must be different, though, IIRC: The same CSS rule will overwrite an earlier one. So you need to include the local file, first, and then load the external one. If the external one isn't available, your local copy will be used.

If you put the CSS file on the local harddisk, this will be pretty cheap.

That said, the browser will not always download the file. It will first check whether the copy in its cache is still current and if it is, it won't download the file again.

Answer (score 0):

You could by default use the 'local.css' and use javascript (using ajax) to load the new one.
If the request can load the new css file it'll ok, else, you just change anything.

Comment: Other way around. He wants to use the local one as a fallback only, so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ehmm...
You coudl use this:

I don't know if  the alternate stylesheet is loaded when the first fails but you could try, if not sure, read this: [A List Apart Tutorial for Changing Stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/)

Answer (score -4):

This can be achieved by JavaScript.
Code should be like this:

```
if( loadcss(first.css) == false) loadcss(second.css);
```

where loadcss is function checks if css is loaded or not

Comment: Um ... this is a correct answer. Why the vote down? You might not like it but that doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I suppose they have downvoted this not because it has to be corrected, but it has to be completed. In this form does it help the asker in any way?